# How to auto-adjust width of ImageView inside TableLayout->TableRow?

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, android-tablelayout

#### tl;tr

[image]

#### Problem

I have multiple `ImageView` components inside an `TableLayout`->`TableRow`. When their height scale down, their width sticks to the original size, leaving a lot of space between adjacent columns. How can I adjust the width to a minimum to have close-by columns?

I already tried using `android:adjustViewBounds` - but nothing happened. Setting a fixed value on the views works - but i hate that plus it won't allow scaling UI.

[Image showing current and desired layout.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDknd.png) (same as in *tl;tr* section)

#### Workspace/Target

Android Studio 2.2.3
min. SDK: API 19
target SDK: API 25
`@drawable/ic_placeholder` dimensions: 46x46px PNG

#### Layout File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="40dp"
      tools:context="...">
  <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:src="@drawable/ic_placeholder" />
  <Space
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
  <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end">

    <TableRow
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="0dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:gravity="end">
      <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:paddingLeft="2dp"
            android:paddingRight="2dp"
            tools:src="@drawable/ic_placeholder" />
      <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:paddingLeft="2dp"
            android:paddingRight="2dp"
            tools:src="@drawable/ic_placeholder" />
      <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:paddingLeft="2dp"
            android:paddingRight="2dp"
            tools:src="@drawable/ic_placeholder" />
      <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:paddingLeft="2dp"
            android:paddingRight="2dp"
            tools:src="@drawable/ic_placeholder" />
    </TableRow>

  </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What are the drawable placeholder dimensions?

Comment: they shrink by height from 46x46 px png file

Comment: do you need that tablelayout with just a single row? i guess you can get the UI you want with a simpler layout

Comment: there actually are/will be 2 more rows below one with text and one with a button.

Answer (score 0):

See if it fits your needs:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context="...">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        tools:src="@drawable/ic_placeholder" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:shrinkColumns="*">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:paddingLeft="2dp"
                android:paddingRight="2dp"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                tools:src="@drawable/ic_placeholder" />

            <ImageView
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:paddingLeft="2dp"
                android:paddingRight="2dp"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                tools:src="@drawable/ic_placeholder" />

            <ImageView
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:paddingLeft="2dp"
                android:paddingRight="2dp"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                tools:src="@drawable/ic_placeholder" />

            <ImageView
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:paddingLeft="2dp"
                android:paddingRight="2dp"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                tools:src="@drawable/ic_placeholder" />

        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```